# How to iterate over a dictionary of arrays (without knowing the key name)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a an object that looks similar to this:

```
[
    {"key1": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"]},
    {"key2": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.191", "20", "0", "2212", "1"]},
    {"key3": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.192", "22", "0", "4376", "0"]}
]
```

However I do NOT know the names of the keys (ie key1, key2 and key3 names are not known to me).

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030759/iterate-through-dictionaries-in-javascript-and-access-values) is almost exactly what I want, except that method requires you to know the names of the keys.

I need to be able to iterate over the key name and it's value array.

I've tried this:

```
for (var i in zk) {
    for (var j in zk[i]) {
        console.log(j)
    }
}
```

But that only prints the key names. How can I iterate through the list as well? In most langues iterating over j seems the logical choice but not in this case. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: `zk[i][j]` is the array ? But you should actually change your datastructure, either use an array of objects or one object with keys for lookup, not both.

Comment: You can use for..of to iterate through values instead of keys https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: `thing.map(Object.values)` or `thing.flatMap(Object.values)` or `thing.flatMap(Object.values).flat()` depending on how exactly you want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's continue from the code sample you have provided.

1) Getting the keys of each element

```
for (let i in zk) {
  for (let j in zk[i]) {
    console.log(j)
  }
}
```

2) Getting the list within each element

```
for (let i in zk) {
  for (let j in zk[i]) {
    console.log(zk[i][j])
  }
}
```

3) Iterating through each list within each element

```
for (let i in zk) {
  for (let j in zk[i]) {
    for (let k = 0; k < zk[i][j].length; k++) {
      console.log(zk[i][j][k])
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), which returns the values of each key-value pair. You can consider using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) too.

```
for (let i in zk) {
  Object.values(zk[i]).map(list => {
    list.map(element => {
      console.log(element);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the object of which value has to be printed

```
for (var i in zk) {
    for (var j in zk[i]) {
        console.log(zk[i][j])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're missing one level of your loop. You have to loop over the outer array, then loop over the keys in each object, then if that key's value is an array loop over that array.

If for example you want to log all the values then you can use `Object.prototype.keys()` it returns an array of the keys in an object so you can try something like this:

```js
const arr = [
        {"key1": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"]},
        {"key2": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.191", "20", "0", "2212", "1"]},
        {"key3": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.192", "22", "0", "4376", "0"]}
    ];

    arr.forEach(x => {
      Object.keys(x).forEach(k => {
        if (Array.isArray(x[k])) {
          x[k].forEach(v => {
            console.log(v);
          });
        } else {
          console.log(x[k]);
        }
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a differetn approach for iterating the given arrays and objects, with

- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for iterating an array,
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) for getting an array of arrays with keys and values and a
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for an array of key/value pairs.

```js
var data = [{ key1: ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"] }, { key2: ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.191", "20", "0", "2212", "1"] }, { key3: ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.192", "22", "0", "4376", "0"] }];

data.forEach((object, outerIndex) =>
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([key, array]) => 
        array.forEach((value, innerIndex) => 
            console.log(outerIndex, key, innerIndex, value)
        )
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) would be helpful if you are trying to iterate over and output each object key and each of the values in the corresponding array. There are more compact ways to do this, but the nested loops should clearly illustrate what is happening.

```js
const arr = [
  {"key1": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"]},
  {"key2": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.191", "20", "0", "2212", "1"]},
  {"key3": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.192", "22", "0", "4376", "0"]}
];

for (const obj of arr) {
  for (const [key, values] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    console.log(`KEY: ${key}`);
    console.log('VALUES: ');
    for (const value of values) {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
}
// Example output from first object...
// KEY: key1
// VALUES: 
// 2019-04-12-14:54:29.190
// 19
// 0
// 4325
// 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In js you always get the keys so what you do is:

```
for (var i in zk) {
    for (var j in zk[i]) { // j wil ben key1, key2 ect
        console.log(zk[i][j]); // arrays  ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"] over where you can itterate
        for (var k in zk[i][j]) {
            console.log(zk[i][j][k]); // "2019-04-12-14:54:29.190" ect
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values`:

```js
const arr = [
    {"key1": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.190", "19", "0", "4325", "1"]},
    {"key2": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.191", "20", "0", "2212", "1"]},
    {"key3": ["2019-04-12-14:54:29.192", "22", "0", "4376", "0"]}
];

arr.forEach(obj => console.log(Object.values(obj)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```